# footmisc: how to avoid having the footnote marker appear as first item after a line-break?

Tags: footmisc

Dear fellow texnocrats,

I am using the standard footmisc package, and the footnote counter sometimes displays as first item on the consecutive line (which looks awkward especially because I place it before the period.

How can I avoid having texts appear like this

11?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the tex code resulting in your issue.

Comment: `this~\footnote{...}?` should work.

Comment: `\footnote` is intended to be placed immediately after the preceding word and a linebreak will then never happen before it,

Comment: @JohnKormylo but do you ever want a space before the footnote symbol?

Comment: David Carlisle and John Kormylo both helped very well, how can I upvote their answers and indicate the question is solved? Sorry

Answer (score 2):

`\footnote` is intended to be placed immediately after the preceding word and a linebreak will then never happen before it.